# Changing WooCommerce Thumbnail in Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a small photography site and looking to protect the images the best I can.

> (I know, I know - you can't protect the images once they're on the
>   internet)

So - to do this, instead of using an annoying *disable-right-click-using-javascript* method, I'm loading the watermarked thumbnail images using base64 to obfuscate the filepath.

**Code I'm using, if anyone's interested. Feel free to suggest improvements/criticise:**

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'shop_catalog' ); ?>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($image[0])); ?>">
```

This works great on `content-single-product.php`, but does anyone know what code is loading the images in the `[best_selling_products]` and `[recent_products]` shortcodes? I'm in `class-wc-shortcodes.php`, but the query doesn't seem to be loading the images from here...

**So why don't I just load small thumbnail images?**
Good question. Because we're planning to sell photos through the site, the high-res image *has* to be loaded as the featured image (to be sent though to the printing API) - and anyone with half a brain can look at the thumbnail url and get the full high-res image url.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this, or am I just best off scrapping the shortcodes and building my own query?

Comment: Just a question why not just load the images with water mark and only load the original high res images on purchase? That's what images store sites are doing, ex. https://www.shutterstock.com. And also you've said it yourself "you can't protect the images once they're on the internet".

Comment: @Jplus2 - that's essentially what I'm trying to do, but the url still needs obfuscating to stop people from investing and finding the high-res image. I don't really care if someone takes the low-res watermarked image. The other option is to create random image urls on upload, but I figured the way in this question was simpler.

Comment: Check out changing all image src with http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19029/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-the-get-image-tag-filter

Comment: "the high-res image has to be loaded as the featured image (to be sent though to the printing API)" could you perhaps modify what you send to the printing API? And send it an alternative image URL in lieu of the featured image?

Comment: Additionally, the loop shortcodes all use the `content-product.php` template, so changes there will be reflected in the shortcodes as well as in your archive loops.

Comment: aha - sometimes all it takes a bit more coffee and a little bit of help from our friends :) Thanks @helgatheviking - I'm not even sure why I didn't think to look in `content-product.php` - but all sorted now.

Comment: Great! Could you write up an answer explaining what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay - so as requested, here's my solution:**

As @helgatheviking mentioned, the template which controls the product overview is`woocommerce/content-product.php` - or as WooCommerce puts it:

> *The template for displaying product content within loops*

There are a number of hooks here, including `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail` - the hook which controls the product thumbnails. So quite simply (in the end) all we need to do is:

**1) Unhook the thumbnails** using: 
`remove_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);`

**2) Add an action with our own custom thumbnail, or anything else:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_custom_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

function woocommerce_custom_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'shop_catalog' );
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' .base64_encode(file_get_contents($image[0])) . '">';
}
```

**Thanks to @helgatheviking for pointing me in the right direction.**

More on WooCommerce Hooks at: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/